# Responsive float div - bad positioning

Tags: html, responsive-design

Im getting crazy about this issue, and I can not see solutions and reason for this behavior.

I have three div with some image and audio within It. CSS for those div:

```
margin: 1%; 
float: left; 
width: 31%; 
min-width: 300px;
```

This CSS makes 1 row and 3 columns, when width of these div is 300px, one must goes down making 2 rows and 2 columns. Here is my trouble, the one which has go down goes to the second column: look this image:[image: Bad 2 column]

How can this be possible??? Im looking for some kind of mistake in css but I found nothing.

container CSS of that div is:

```
width: 84%;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 9%;
overflow: hidden;
```

Some clue? Other way of looking this may be How can align "float: left" divs to the right?

Any help would be apreciatte...

Comment: please show us a working example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you show us more? It's rather hard to debug from this alone. Does this occur on all browsers?

Comment: for me this example works fine : http://jsfiddle.net/f84EH/

Answer (score 0):

I have to answer myself: so easy as put height to img within divs...

Thank you!!!